# Как сформировать Api запрос на python requests?

Tags: python, requests, telegram

Нужен бот, который будет подавать жалобы на пользователей, каналов и ботов.
На сайте telegram api (https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.report) нашел метод messages.report
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако,  я не очень понял, как мне сформировать запрос и заполнить все необходимые поля, чтобы программа работала

PS
Если реализация этого метода будет в какой либо библиотеке, будет даже лучше

Comment: А на что вообще бот может жаловаться?

Comment: На эксплуатацию кожаными мешками )))